# What do I do if my thesis is stolen

Tags: thesis, copyright, scams

I submitted my thesis in September. But because of nervousness I wasn’t confident with the way I wrote the result section, though I had researched extensively on it.

I was going through YouTube on October 1st and came across a website. Looking at the website and email, I felt it was legitimate and I decided to ask a question just to clear up a confusion I had.

My intention was not to send anything to them but somehow they convinced me to send my thesis. Then they started blackmailing me by threatening to contact my school, but this doesn’t worry me because I have documented every step of my project and I have evidences. My main concern is that they also threatened to sell my hard work to one of their client.

Is this something I can take legal action on? I have already reported them to National cyber security centre.

Comment: It is very difficult to understand how they can "blackmail" you. Do you think your degree is at risk? What is your concern?

Comment: I am not sure why you're worried. You already submitted your thesis on 9/28. Your school has the record. It's a done deal. How can they steal it ?

Comment: @Buffy I begged for them to delete my work they said I must pay £150 consultation fee, later they said I should pay £1475 which I did not give into because why will I pay for a work I did solely on my own. I am concerned my work will be sold to someone else before I can even have an opportunity to publish it. I am also worried they may lie to my school.

Comment: @Nobody I am worried they will sell my hard work to someone else before I even have opportunity to publish it.

Comment: We are not lawyers here and we can't advise on any legal route you can take.

Comment: Even if they do sell it, what do you think a buyer is going to do with it?  Try and submit it as a thesis at another university (nasty, but doesn't directly harm you)?  Try and adapt it into papers and get them accepted in journals faster than you can (could be a problem, but relies on the buyer having both a reasonable level of skill and a lot of luck - and even if they do manage it, you can always point after the fact to your thesis submission date for a claim of priority)?

Comment: @DanielHatton Not only would the OP be able to show priority for the work, but can also show *this question* as evidence that the extortionists were threatening to publish the work as their own. Anyone who *later* attempts to publish the work (presumably under their own names) are effectively providing evidence for both plagiarism and being complicit in extortion. The latter charge might not stick unless it could be shown that they were knowing accomplices (IANAL), but either way, attempting to publish this work is going to cause the bad guys a lot more trouble than it would the OP.

Comment: Your thesis will be published by your university. So all your hard work will be publicly available to the world. These criminals could always sell your published thesis, even without ever having made contact with you. I do not see how their threats would concern you at all.

Comment: I think it's important to add that, if you did even the bare minimum required for a PhD, there can be *no doubt at all* that it's your work: this is partly what the Viva process is for, anyone can plagiarise (or ChatGPT) a thesis, but to talk confidently about every part of it for hours is hard to fake.

Comment: *"My Intention was not to send anything to them but somehow they got me to send my thesis."* That is some of the most creative verbal gymnastics to deflect responsibility for your mistake.

Comment: @servaes I am not deflecting responsibility for my mistake. I did acknowledge from the beginning I made a mistake. But this project is my hard work, and I don’t want a project I suffered and took my time to do to get sold to someone else.

Comment: @Bergi Informing someone that you'll report them for a crime isn't blackmail. I don't see what GDPR has to do with anything, a thesis isn't personal data. Good luck bringing a copyright suit for no monetary damages against this random anonymous person on the internet, or "forcing them" to delete things from their own computer. None of these are realistic courses of action.

Comment: @DanielHatton In the humanities, a PhD thesis should eventually become a published book, which is necessary for a faculty position. If the work is widely distributed/pirated, there is a belief that a publisher won't pick it up, as they can't make a financial return on it. This is significantly different from the sciences where nobody cares about the thesis as the content is often already published in journals or conferences. Correcting Basil Borque's comment, universities may publish it, but they are often paywalled, for this reason.

Comment: I agree that doing what Buffy suggests in their answer is a good idea, just in case. However, I don't think you have reasons to panic. What seems most likely to me is that these scammers are just trying to scare you, but if you don't give in to their threats they can't really do that much to you.

Comment: They are likely bluffing. I personally would not inform them of my next steps, but if you want to scare them back, you could tell them that you officially report them (of course, this should be what you in fact did - don't bluff with criminals, they are better at this than you).

Answer (score 59):

Inform your advisor and the department, maybe also the Dean of the school what happened. Don't pay any money to extortionists. Let the authorities deal with it. Your university may have a legal department that can provide assistance.

Keep a watch to see if your work appears elsewhere, though I doubt it will, and inform any publisher of the details if it happens.

Move quickly to get it published if that is your goal.

Perhaps warn YouTube of the issue, though that may be difficult.

And, be more careful online in the future. There are a lot of scammers out there.

Comment: In addition to that i would suggest blocking all communication with the scammers.
OP seems a bit influence-able (sorry but it is what it is from your situation), therefore DO NOT continue any communication with the scammers. Ignore if you can, block if you cannot. Don't give them any more power.

Answer (score 16):

It's worth remembering that in most locales around the world, you owned the copyright to your thesis the moment you recorded it in a durable format (on paper, in an electronic document, etc).  Someone else possessing a copy of your thesis does not dilute your rights at all, nor does it grant them any rights at all.  If they try to do something with it, you have all the same remedies as you would for any other type of copyrighted work.  Keep all your original drafts, data, submission records, etc., then block the scammer and enjoy being done with your thesis.

Comment: @Mazura [bad idea](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/93796/is-it-legal-to-intentionally-wait-before-filing-a-copyright-lawsuit-to-maximize).

Answer (score 3):

Do nothing.  Ignore them.

Nobody will buy your thesis from scammers or anyone else.  The scammers have no power over you.  If you try to take "legal action" it is likely they cannot be found.

Informing your advisor, dean, or anyone else at the university will not achieve anything.